# Delete Elastic Beanstalk Cron

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using elastic beanstalk's cron.yaml to trigger periodic tasks. It works great, however, if I redeploy my code the cron gets fired twice. Deploy again and the task will get fired 3 times, etc. How do I delete the existing crons so when I deploy there is only one instance of the cron?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `cron.yaml`, which adds the cron job to all EB instances that get deployed, you can use `.ebextensions` to define commands that run on each of your instances and qualify these commands to only run on one instance using `leader_only: true`.

E.g.,

**.ebextensions/01_setup_cron.config**

```
container_commands:
    01_some_cron_job:
        command: "cat .ebextensions/your_cron.txt > /etc/cron.d/your_Cron && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/your_cron"
        leader_only: true
```

**.ebextensions/your_cron.txt**

```
* * * * * root /usr/bin/do-something.sh

# Don't forget to put a blank new line at the end of the cron - cron won't work without it
```

This will copy the cron file to `/etc/cron.d/` for one instance only (the "leader" instance), and will mean your cron only runs once.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here: [Running a cron job in Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523044/running-a-cron-job-in-elastic-beanstalk)

Cron tasks are implemented with an SQS queue. If an endpoint in cron.yaml returns anything other than 200, the triggering message stays in the queue and will be retried over and over.

Once you're sure all your cron endpoints return 200, purge the queue and the redundant calls will stop.